# write function by reference parameter in c++

Tags: c++

I write a program with C++ and I want to change it to a function. this function should return 3 value so I used parameters by reference. when I run it , C++ give me syntax error.  I use miracle library for big numbers and think that miracle causes this error . please give me your advice for solving my problem.
this is function definition :

```
big Predictor(big X,big Y,big Z,big &X_out,big &Y_out,big &Z_out)
 {
 }
```

call the function:

```
 Predictor(X_w,Y_w,Z_w,X2_W_Out,Y2_W_Out,Z2_W_Out);
```

and the error:

[image]

after adding ebrick.cpp:
[image]

Comment: @ravi this is a type for using big numbers .I use miracl library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your file has a `.c` extension, so the compiler assumes it's C. C doesn't have references, hence the errors.

If it's meant to be C++, then give it a conventional C++ extension like `.cc`, `.cpp` or `.cxx`. If it's meant to be C, then use pointers instead of references.

Comment: thanks Mike .I get what you mean but I'm  not a professional programmer and couldn't do what you said.when I want to start writing this program ,first I couldn't add miracl library.some one wrote a program that use miracl in his program . so I just copy my code to his program and could get result. "ebreik.c" had contained the source code. If I created a new project my problems would be more and more . can you give me your email?I want to send you all of my project. maybe after that you can explain me what should I do .

Comment: @zahra: Sorry, I'm not a consultant. If you want to program, you'll need to learn the language, and figure out how your tools work. In the meantime, either rename the file, or stick to the C language (which doesn't allow references). If you have any specific problems, ask another question.

Comment: OK thanks any way . I can find " ebrick.cpp " in miracle source too. but I don't know how can I add it to my project. I add it in this way but it seems that visual studio can't accept it.I copy this file to my project folder too . what's wrong ?

Comment: @zahra: I've no idea, I never use Visual Studio.

Comment: I can understand what happened :P when I added miracl , I just add the file with .C extension . because of that it can't detect this file. am I right?

Comment: OK . I appreciate you for every thing. :)